# Query works in MySQL Workbench but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that works perfectly in MySQL Workbench but returns some columns as NULL when executed in my PHP webpage.

*EverSQL validator* says there is a syntax error without specifying what it is, which is not helpful. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
$query = "
SELECT CONCAT(ade.`type`, ' ', ade.subtype) AS `type`, 
COUNT(*) AS count, 
@total := SUM(ade.total_co2_kg) AS total, 
ROUND(SUM(ade.raw_materials) / @total * 100, 2) AS raw_materials, 
ROUND(SUM(ade.supplying) / @total * 100, 2) AS supplying, 
ROUND(SUM(ade.making) / @total * 100, 2) AS making, ROUND(SUM(ade.assembly) / @total * 100, 2) AS assembly, 
ROUND(SUM(ade.distribution) / @total * 100, 2) AS distribution
FROM glpi_plugin_gtm_computermodels_association AS ass_mod
JOIN glpi_plugin_gtm_ademe_co2_emissions_for_manufacture AS ade 
ON ass_mod.gtm_ademe_id = ade.id
GROUP BY ade.`type`, ade.subtype
ORDER BY total DESC";

$results = $DB->request($query);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo implode(', ', $result);
}
```

**Result in MySQL Workbench:**

```
'Computer Laptop', '1', '156.00000', '76.92', '1.21', '0.48', '1.22', '20.32'
```

**Result in PHP webpage:**

```
Computer Laptop, 1, 156.00000, , , , ,
```

Comment: You shouldn't depend on being able to use `@total` later in the same select list.

Comment: I'm confused; how do you know to which type a subtype belongs?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the reason why it would not work properly in PHP, but I found a workaround by not using the SUM operator and multiplying the results by the count afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't guarantee that expressions in the `SELECT` list will be evaluated from left to right. So you can't safely use a variable that's assigned in one expression in a later expression.

Instead of the `@total` variable, write out its expression each time.

```
$query = "SELECT 
CONCAT(ade.`type`, ' ', ade.subtype) AS `type`, 
COUNT(*) AS count, 
SUM(ade.total_co2_kg) AS total, 
ROUND(SUM(ade.raw_materials) / SUM(ade.total_co2_kg) * 100, 2) AS raw_materials, 
ROUND(SUM(ade.supplying) / SUM(ade.total_co2_kg) * 100, 2) AS supplying, 
ROUND(SUM(ade.making) / SUM(ade.total_co2_kg) * 100, 2) AS making, ROUND(SUM(ade.assembly) / SUM(ade.total_co2_kg) * 100, 2) AS assembly, 
ROUND(SUM(ade.distribution) / SUM(ade.total_co2_kg) * 100, 2) AS distribution
FROM glpi_plugin_gtm_computermodels_association AS ass_mod
JOIN glpi_plugin_gtm_ademe_co2_emissions_for_manufacture AS ade ON ass_mod.gtm_ademe_id = ade.id
GROUP BY ade.`type`, ade.subtype
ORDER BY total DESC";
```